# 2D char array looks good while building but becomes one big concatenated mess later

Tags: unix, gcc

Everything looks good during assignment but when I access the results outside, I get a concatenation of all the array element..

```
#include<string.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int sqr(int r)
{
        int i,temp=1;
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
                temp*=2;
        }
        return temp;
}
char arrbin[20][8];
void  toBinary(int ascii)
{
        int i,j,len=0,tascii=ascii;
        char binary[8]={""};
        strcpy(binary,"");
        while(1)
        {
                int bit=ascii%2;
                char bit1[2];
                snprintf(bit1,sizeof(bit1),"%d",bit);
                strcat(binary,bit1);
                if(ascii!=1)
                        ascii=ascii/2;
                if(ascii==1)
                        break;
        }
        if(tascii!=1)
                strcat(binary,"1");
        len=strlen(binary);
        for(i=0;i<(8-len);i++)
        {
                strcat(binary,"0");
        }
        printf("\n%s",binary);
        strcpy(arrbin[tascii-1],binary);
        strcat(arrbin[tascii-1],"\0");

}
}
void toBin(int bits)
{
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<bits;i++)
        {
                toBinary(i+1);
        }
}
void disp(int bits)
{
        int i;
        printf("\n%d:",bits);
        for(i=0;i<bits;i++)
                printf("\n\n%s",arrbin[i]);
                //hear print all element concat and return output
}
int main()
{
        char bin[100]={""},arr[100];
        int r=0;
        int val[10];
        int m;//length
        int temp=0;//for the assign value to  position
        int i,j,bits;//how many box are there
        system("clear");
        printf("Enter Binary:");
        scanf("%s",bin);
        m=strlen(bin);
        while((m+r+1)>sqr(r))
        {
                r++;
        }
        bits=m+r;
        printf("m:%d\nr:%d \n-----\nbits=%d\n",m,r,bits);
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
                val[i]=sqr(i);
        for(i=0;i<bits;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<r;j++)
                {
                        if((i+1)==val[j])
                        {
                                arr[i]='r';
                  break;
                        }
                }
                if(arr[i]!='r')
                        arr[i]=bin[temp++];
        }
        toBin(bits);
        disp(bits);

        for(i=0;i<bits;i++)
                printf("%c ",arr[i]);
        getchar();
        return 0;
}
```

As I build the array in `toBinary()`, everything looks good. But later in `disp()` all two dimension array print output like

**Output:**

```
Enter Binary:1001001001001
m:13
r:5
-----
bits=18

100000000
010000000
110000000
001000000
101000000
011000000
111000000
000100000
100100000
010100000
110100000
001100000
101100000
011100000
111100000
000010000
100010000
010010000
18
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
01000000110000000010000010100000011000001110000000010000100100000101000011010000001100001011000001110000111100000000100010001000010010000
r r 1 r 0 0 1 r 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 r 0 1
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: My quesion is only that when i creting 2D array at that time i print value of arrbin then its print appropriate data but after out of that function why thats combine??

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to terminate the individual entries with a `\0` byte.

> A string is a contiguous sequence of code units terminated by the first zero code (written '\0' and corresponding to the ASCII null character).

([source: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling#Definitions))

While you build the array, this doesn't matter since you always only print the last element.

Another bug: `arrbin[1]` in `disp()` should probably be `arrbin[i]`.

Hint: When looking for bugs, try to reduce the problem, first.

You may also want to read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Comment: But every single element i print in c Language then its works but in unix+c+gcc in how this type of problem arises.. this same code running in c properly then how can i solve this..

Comment: sir Aaron Digulla.. i am telling you that, i am creating this program in Putty which is run on unix server and the program is run on gcc. I think now you are understood why i am write unix+c+gcc..                in short, this 2D array i print in c with turbo c compiler there is no problem and works properly but in gcc  compiler when i print any single array element then hows its combine that think i cant understand.. thanks sir

Comment: Please put changes in my code if you can suggest me. thank you

Comment: Explain to me what make something a string in C.

Comment: in c staring is char array

Comment: Char arrays *can* be strings (among other things). You're still missing the most important aspect. Can you tell me how C determines how **long** a string is?

Comment: I am edited my code please watch again.. i am applying your suggest thing in program.. now you can suggest other then tell me please ... thank you very much..

Comment: Can you tell me how C determines how **long** a string is? Hint: Add `printf("%d\n", strlen(arrbin[0]));` after `strcpy(arrbin[tascii-1],binary);`

Comment: in the same function toBinary() it before return 0 and after that apply strcpy(arrbin[tascii-1],binary); its return 8..

Comment: Good. So now you have an array with 8 characters. You put 8 characters into it and then append an additional `\0` character. Where do you think that 0 byte goes?